# Issues querying Athena table where source bucket is from a different account

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I have created Athena tables for files that are in S3 bucket which do not belong to my account.
The tables are partitioned and when i run the MSCK REPAIR TABLE command it is successful and shows the partitions not in metastore. But when i query the table it gives following error

"Your query has the following error(s):

Insufficient permissions to execute the query.

This query ran against the "......" database, unless qualified by the query. Please post the error message on our forum or contact customer support with Query Id: ..........."

What could be the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are describing is caused by a wrongly set access policy. I would guess, that the Athena account has the `listBucket` privilege, but not the `getObject`.

As a sample, I used the following bucket policy to test the cross account access.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:ListBucket"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::bucketname","arn:aws:s3:::bucketname/*"],
      "Principal": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Please change the principal in that sample or your data will be public for the whole internet.

Comment: I am looking at the bucket permissions of the source AWS account. Under Public access, i can see List objects, Write objects, Read bucket permissions, Write bucket permissions granted to "Any AWS user". Isn't this enough? There are no Accounts added under "Access for other AWS accounts" however.

Comment: For me, adding READ access in the console to any user didn't work. I had to explicitly use the bucket policy to get it running.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issues, it turned out that my table was created using AWS Glue. Adding permissions to Glue solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Even I had the same issue, but the catch is sometimes the policy propagation takes time depending on the different region your services are placed.

- Providing a "*" value of Principal might not be a good idea as this will make your bucket globally accessible.
- And then grant all the s3 permissions to the other AWS account.
- Now since we have given the root access to another account, Athena being a service inside that will be able to make required connections.
- Just to make it clear, you just need to put the bucket name as if the bucket was present in the same AWS account and don't need to worry about the location.

Below is an example of policy sample which I am referring to:

`{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Corss-Account-Permissions",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::AWS-ACCOUNT-ID:root"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::example-bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::example-bucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}`